# Is the description $\bigwedge^{k} V_{\mathbb{C}}^{*} = \bigwedge^{k} V^{*} \oplus i\bigwedge^{k} V^{*}$ right?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, multilinear-algebra

I am trying to learn about complex differential forms and I'm having some problem understanding the equality presented in the title, which I have seen in Volker Scheidemann's book "Introduction to Complex Analysis in Several Variables". I will leave below a screenshot of the statement in the book.

As he says, each $\mu \in \bigwedge^{k} V_{\mathbb{C}}^{*}$ is a real valued alternating multivariable function on $V_{\mathbb{C}}^{k}$, so to me, the equality does not makes sense as an element on the right seems to be a complex valued function right? What am I missing?

I appreciate all the help in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Scheidemann writes $\bigwedge^k V_{\mathbb C}^*=\bigwedge^k V^*\oplus i\bigwedge^k V^*.$ Notice that there are no $\mathbb C$ subscripts on the right hand side. One way to think about it is like this: if you fix a basis $\{v_j\}_{j=1}^n$ for $V,$ then $V_\mathbb C$ has $\mathbb R$-basis $\{v_j, iv_j\}_{j=1}^n.$ Then the real dual space is spanned by $\{\varphi_j,\psi_j\}_{j=1}^n$ where $$\varphi_j(v_k)=\delta_{jk}\\ \varphi_j(iv_k)=0\\ \psi(v_k)=0\\ \psi_j(iv_k)=\delta_{jk}$$ and the $\varphi_j$'s and the $\psi_j$'s are real linear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood what you pointed out. However, I still don't understand the equality since it seems to me that an element in the right hand side is of the form $\mu + i\nu$, where $\mu$ and $\nu$ are real valued. Then, isn't the sum a complex valued function?

Comment: Maybe the $i$ in the direct sum decomposition is a little misleading. It's just there to signify that the left hand summand acts on the "real" vectors while the right hand summand acts on the "imaginary" vectors. The answer you get when you sum the two is still real.

Comment: Ok, that’s what I was thinking, but I had to confirm if I was missing something